# Visual Studio 2012 - Deleting multiple SSIS Column Mappings in Data Flow Task

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

Is there a way to remove all column mappings in a SSIS data flow task in one step? In the example below, if I wanted to remove all the mappings I would have to individually click each arrow (using 'ctrl+click') and then hit the 'delete' button.

This is not ideal if I have a table with >20 columns!
Does anyone have any tips or tricks that could help?

Thanks!

[image: SSISColumnMappings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-Click the background and you should have the option to `'Select All Mappings'`, Repeat Right-Click `'Delete selected mappings'`.

[image: Right-Click]